# Change color of contenteditable div when value equals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, background-color, contenteditable

I have a table containing some contenteditable divs:

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="change">
```

The JS code below makes the divs change color depending on what content they have when page loads.

But how do I change color on the fly and prevent users from writing anything else than hello, goodmorning and goodbye? If change the contenteditable string from goodmorning to hello and then click outside of that div, I would like the background-color and text color of the div to change from yellow to green.

Javascript code:

```
function coloring() {
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td:contains(goodmorning)").css("background-color", "yellow").css("color", "yellow");
    $("td:contains(hello)").css("background-color", "green").css("color", "green");
    $("td:contains(goodbye)").css("background-color", "red").css("color", "red");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Listen for the change event on the select input, grab its value then change the color of your container using CSS.

```
$('#colorChange').change(function(){
   var selectedColor = "red";
   $('#container').css('background-color', selectedColor);
});
```

You can check content like this : `$(this).val()`
And for example, create a Switch Case to add different color according to div value

Comment: Tried this and some variations but couldn't get it to work. Not that good yet but all help appreciated `$('.change[contenteditable]').change(function(){
   var selectedColor = "white";

   $(this).val().css('background-color', 'selectedColor');

switch ($(this).val()) {
    case "hello":
        $('.change').css('background-color', 'yellow');
        break;
    case "goodmorning":
        $('.change').css('background-color', 'green');
        break;
    case "goodbye":
        $('.change').css('background-color', 'red');
        break;
} 

});`

Answer (score 0):

You need only html and javascript to do that!

Here's html code:

```
<div id='div' contenteditable='true' oninput='change()'>
```

In this code, I have used id(div) and `oninput` attribute which triggers javascript's `change()` function everytime when users change anything in that div.

Here's javascript code:

```
function change(){
var text=document.getElementById("div").innerHTML;
if(text=="hello"){
    document.getElementById('div').style.backgroundColor=("green");
    }
else{
document.getElementById('div').style.backgroundColor=("white");};
/*LIKE THIS, YOU CAN CODE MORE WHAT YOU WANT*/
};
```

JavaScript code detects what is written in that div and changes div's background color according to that.